# In c3 Chart add the Exponential log values in x axis and Between tick values need space

Tags: charts, c3.js, exponential

1.The x-axis should be scientific format values if <1. In the picture, there are two different values which are automatically set by the used widget (10−8=1−7 and 10−7=1−6). If possible always set as 1E.. and not 10E..
2. The x-axis should be standard value if ≥1. (1=10,10=11, …)
3.The min value = 1−9 and the max value = 100.

Like a attached image.

[image: Expected Output Image]

But i got the output like tick value is merged with other value.

[image: Need tick value space.]

I want to Show a output like Image 1.

Thank you.

Comment: Currently it is not possible through config or API.
Refer https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/252

Comment: Thank you for your quick response...